# Generics : List<? extends Animal> is same as List<Animal>?

Tags: java, generics, covariance, extends, contravariance

I am just trying to understand the `extends` keyword in Java Generics.

`List<? extends Animal>` means we can stuff any object in the `List` which **IS A** `Animal`

then won't the following also mean the same thing:

```
List<Animal>
```

Can someone help me know the difference between the above two? To me `extends` just sound redundant here.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not to use  `<T extendsAnimal> void foo(List<T> param)`?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`List<Dog>` is a subtype of `List<? extends Animal>`, but not a subtype of `List<Animal>`.

Why is `List<Dog>` not a subtype of `List<Animal>`? Consider the following example:

```
void mySub(List<Animal> myList) {
    myList.add(new Cat());
}
```

If you were allowed to pass a `List<Dog>` to this function, you would get a run-time error.

---

EDIT: Now, if we use `List<? extends Animal>` instead, the following will happen:

```
void mySub(List<? extends Animal> myList) {
    myList.add(new Cat());     // compile error here
    Animal a = myList.get(0);  // works fine 
}
```

You *could* pass a `List<Dog>` to this function, but the compiler realizes that adding something to the list could get you into trouble. If you use `super` instead of `extends` (allowing you to pass a `List<LifeForm>`), it's the other way around.

```
void mySub(List<? super Animal> myList) {
    myList.add(new Cat());     // works fine
    Animal a = myList.get(0);  // compile error here, since the list entry could be a Plant
}
```

The theory behind this is [Co- and Contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Java).

Comment: In you first example,you would get a compiler error rather than a run-time error if you pass a List<dog> to a List<Animal>

Comment: @DonLi: Indeed. That's why I use the [second conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Second_conditional): *"If you **were allowed**..."*, i.e. in the hypothetical scenario that the compiler considered `List<Dog>` to be a subtype of `List<Animal>`.

Answer (score 47):

With `List<Animal>`, you know what you have is definitely a list of animals. It's not necessary for all of them to actually be exactly 'Animal's - they could also be derived types. For example, if you have a List of Animals, it makes sense that a couple could be Goats, and some of them Cats, etc - right?

For example this is totally valid:

```
List<Animal> aL= new List<Animal>();
aL.add(new Goat());
aL.add(new Cat());
Animal a = aL.peek();
a.walk(); // assuming walk is a method within Animal
```

Of course, the following would *not* be valid:

```
aL.peek().meow(); // we can't do this, as it's not guaranteed that aL.peek() will be a Cat
```

---

With `List<? extends Animal>`, you're making a statement about the *type of list* you're dealing with.

For example:

```
List<? extends Animal> L;
```

This is actually *not* a declaration of the type of object L can *hold*. **It's a statement about what kinds of lists L can reference.**

For example, we could do this:

```
L = aL; // remember aL is a List of Animals
```

But now all the compiler knows about L is that it is a *List of [either Animal or a subtype of Animal]s*

So now the following is not valid:

```
L.add(new Animal()); // throws a compiletime error
```

Because for all we know, L could be referencing a list of Goats - to which we cannot add an Animal.

Here's why:

```
List<Goat> gL = new List<Goat>(); // fine
gL.add(new Goat()); // fine
gL.add(new Animal()); // compiletime error
```

In the above, we're trying to cast an Animal as a Goat. That doesn't work, because what if after doing that we tried to make that Animal do a 'headbutt', like a goat would? We don't necessarily know that the Animal can do that.

Comment: +1 for "This is actually not a declaration of the type of object L can hold. It's a statement about what kinds of lists L can reference."

Comment: and for the same reason you can not do `L.add(new Goat())` coz L could be referencing to a list of Dogs to which you can not add Goat to :)

Answer (score 17):

It is not. `List<Animal>` says that the value which is assigned to this variable must be of "type" `List<Animal>`. This however doesn't mean that there must only be `Animal` objects, there can be subclasses too.

```
List<Number> l = new ArrayList<Number>();
l.add(4); // autoboxing to Integer
l.add(6.7); // autoboxing to Double
```

You use the `List<? extends Number>` construct if you are interest in an list which got `Number` objects, but the List object itself doesn't need to be of type `List<Number>` but can any other list of subclasses (like `List<Integer>`).

This is sometime use for method arguments to say *"I want a list of `Numbers`, but I don't care if it is just `List<Number>`, it can be a `List<Double>` too"*. This avoid some weird down casts if you have a list of some subclasses, but the method expects a list of the baseclass.

```
public void doSomethingWith(List<Number> l) {
    ...
}

List<Double> d = new ArrayList<Double>();
doSomethingWith(d); // not working
```

This is not working as you expecting `List<Number>`, not a `List<Double>`. But if you wrote `List<? extends Number>` you can pass `List<Double>` objects even as they aren't `List<Number>` objects.

```
public void doSomethingWith(List<? extends Number> l) {
    ...
}

List<Double> d = new ArrayList<Double>();
doSomethingWith(d); // works
```

**Note:** This whole stuff is unrelated to inheritance of the objects in the list itself. You still can add `Double` and `Integer` objects in a `List<Number>` list, with or without `? extends` stuff.

Comment: hmmm.. getting it. Nice explanation