# Why won't this cast work?

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I have the following code:

```
  var commitmentItems = new List<CommitmentItem<ITransaction>>();
  commitmentItems.Add(new CapitalCallCommitmentItem());
```

And I get the following error:

```
Argument '1': cannot convert from 'Models.CapitalCallCommitmentItem' to
'Models.CommitmentItem<Models.ITransaction>'
```

However, `CapitalCallCommitmentItem` inherits from `CommitmentItem<CapitalCall>`, and `CapitalCall` implements `ITransaction`. So why the error?

Here is a better example:

`CapitalCall` implements `ITransaction`

```
            var test = new List<ITransaction>();
            test.Add(new CapitalCall());
            var test2 = new List<List<ITransaction>>();
            test.Add(new List<CapitalCall>()); // error.
```

Comment: read through the co-/contravariance FAQ. It is a very good starting point for people unfamiliar with this topic, as it is somewhat a brain-teaser until you get used to it. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understanding why this doesn't work can be kind of tricky, so here's an analogous example, replacing the classes in your code with some well-known classes from the framework to act as placeholders and (hopefully) illustrate the potential pitfalls of such desired functionality:

```
// Note: replacing CommitmentItem<T> in your example with ICollection<T>
// and ITransaction with object.
var list = new List<ICollection<object>>();

// If the behavior you wanted were possible, then this should be possible, since:
// 1. List<string> implements ICollection<string>; and
// 2. string inherits from object.
list.Add(new List<string>());

// Now, since list is typed as List<ICollection<object>>, our innerList variable
// should be accessible as an ICollection<object>.
ICollection<object> innerList = list[0];

// But innerList is REALLY a List<string>, so although this SHOULD be
// possible based on innerList's supposed type (ICollection<object>),
// it is NOT legal due to innerList's actual type (List<string>).
// This would constitute undefined behavior.
innerList.Add(new object());
```

Answer (score 6):

Because that would need `CommitmentItem<CapitalCall>` to be covariant so that it is assignable to `CommitmentItem<ITransaction>`, which it currently not supported.

C# 4 added support for co- and contravariance in interfaces, but not for classes.

Therefore, if you're using C# 4 and you can use an interface such as `ICommitmentItem<>` instead of `CommitmentItem<>`, you might be able to get what you want by using the new features of C# 4.

Comment: For additional reference, see this MSDN article, which pretty much exactly describes several ways to work around this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228359%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: @jdmichal, thanks for posting the link! It is however outdated in some parts. For the current status of co- and contravariance, have a look at the FAQ: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Let's shorten these names.

```
C = CapitalCallCommentItem
D = CommitmentItem
E = CapitalCall
I = ITransaction
```

So your question is that you have:

```
interface I { }
class D<T>
{
    public M(T t) { }
}
class C : D<E> { } 
class E : I { }
```

And your question is "why is this illegal?"

```
D<E> c = new C(); // legal
D<I> d = c; // illegal
```

Suppose that was legal and deduce an error. c has a method M which takes an E. Now you say

```
class F : I { }
```

Suppose it was legal to assign c to d. Then it would also be legal to call d.M(new F()) because F implements I. But d.M is a method that takes an E, not an F.

Allowing this feature enables you to write programs that compile cleanly and then violate type safety at runtime. The C# language has been carefully designed so that the number of situations in which the type system can be violated at runtime are at a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

*Note - I think Lucero and Eric Lippert himself have provided better direct answers to the question, but I think this is still valuable supplementary material.*

Because C# 3.0 doesn't support covariance or contravariance of generic arguments. (And C# 4.0 has limited support for interfaces only.) See here for an explanation of covariance and contravariance, and some insight into the thinking that went on as the C# team were looking at putting this features into C# 4.0:

- [Covariance and contravariance in C#, part 1](https://ericlippert.com/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-1/)
- [Covariance and Contravariance in C#, Part Two: Array Covariance](https://web.archive.org/web/20151108023642/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx)
- [Covariance and Contravariance in C#, Part Three: Method Group Conversion Variance](https://web.archive.org/web/20151205153418/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/19/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-three-member-group-conversion-variance.aspx)
- [Covariance and Contravariance in C#, Part Four: Real Delegate Variance](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905100842/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/22/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-four-real-delegate-variance.aspx)
- [Covariance and Contravariance In C#, Part Five: Higher Order Functions Hurt My Brain](https://web.archive.org/web/20151029232803/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/24/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-five-higher-order-functions-hurt-my-brain.aspx)

Actually, he just keeps writing and writing! Here's everything he's tagged with ["covariance and contravariance"](https://ericlippert.com/category/covariance-and-contravariance/).

Comment: interesting, but the article doesnt say anything about covariance in generic arguments?

Comment: Ah, it's the first in a series. I didn't realise there weren't links between them. I'll add the others...

Comment: Be careful not to post outdated links. Co- and contravariance on generic interfaces (and delegates) have been introduced with .NET 4 / VS2010.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning my post. :-)
Note that not only interfaces, but also delegates benefit from the new feature. Also the FAQ points to some of Eric's more current blog articles as well.

Comment: @glorfindel thanks for the edit, but I felt the "link link link" text was less helpful than just showing the URLs. I've replaced it with the article titles, which should be better than either.

Comment: @Weeble yes, that's on my to do list, to automatically replace those with the titles of the pages instead. Thanks for the ping!

Answer (score 1):

Because "`A` is subtype of `B`" *does not* imply that "`X<A>` is a subtype of `X<B>`".

Let me give you an example. Assume that `CommitmentItem<T>` has a method `Commit(T t)`, and consider the following function:

```
void DoSomething(CommitmentItem<ITransaction> item) {
    item.Commit(new SomethingElseCall());
}
```

This should work, since `SomethingElseCall` is a subtype of `ITransaction`, just like `CapitalCall`.

Now assume that `CommitmentItem<CapitalCall>` were a subtype of `CommitmentItem<ITransaction>`. Then you could do the following:

```
DoSomething(new CommitmentItem<CapitalCall>());
```

What would happen? You'd get a type error in the middle of `DoSomething`, because a `SomethingElseCall` is passed where a `CapitalCall` was expected. Thus, `CommitmentItem<CapitalCall>` is *not* a subtype of `CommitmentItem<ITransaction>`.

In Java, this problem can be solved by using the `extends` and `super` keywords, cf. [question 2575363](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575363). Unfortunately, C# lacks such a keyword.