# How to cast List<? extends Foo> to List<Foo>

Tags: java, spring-batch

Spring Batch's [ItemWriter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemWriter.html) interface is this:

```
write(List<? extends T> items);
```

I'd like the ItemWriter to call a Service but my service has this:

```
process(List<T> items);
```

AFAIK, Java Generics are strict about casting types within collections.

Comment: Why does your service have `process(List<T> items)` and not `process(List<? extends T> items)`?

Comment: Because that's what I WANT. I don't have to adhere to what Spring says.

Comment: Why do you want that? Are you inserting elements into items (the only functionality you would lose by making it a wildcard)?

Comment: As a Service, the signature is clean and declarative with List<T> than a wildcard, which the service doesn't need. (Yes, useful for other cases though).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just go ahead and cast it. For reading, `List<? extends Foo>` is certainly a `List<Foo>`, the cast is absolutely safe. You can wrap it with `Collections.unmodifiableList()` if you are paranoid.

```
List<? extends Foo> foos1 = ...;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Foo> foos2 = (List<Foo>)(List<?>)foos1;
```

Comment: Brilliant. You are GOD>
PS: Note why Java Generics SUCK.

Comment: Why the extra (List<?>) cast?

Answer (score 7):

Ensure that your method receives an object that inherits from T, and then perform a cast.

Or change the signature of your method to be equal to the write method.

Comment: Why should I CHANGE my signature for Spring? NO.

Comment: I said I was not to change, just gave a suggestion. He could use the given cast option.

Answer (score 5):

```java
List<? extends Foo> list1 = ...
List<Foo> list2 = Collections.unmodifiableList(list1);
```

Reason why `list2` has to be read-only view of `list1` is nicely explained in an answer of [Generics : List is same as List?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2575591/639687)

Answer (score 2):

If your service allows `? extends T`, then that's what the type should be. Currently, it says what's passed in must be exactly `T`.

Comment: He explicitly says that the service accepts List<T>, not List<? extends T>.

Answer (score 1):

Gennerics in Java helps you only in compilation time. You can cast anything, make sure that the value is castable for the new type.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just cast it since you know that if you've got a type that extends `Foo` that it *is a* `Foo`?
Something like this:

```
write(List<? extends Foo> items) {
    //noinspection unchecked
    process( (List<Foo>) items );
}

process(List<Foo> items) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Be sure to catch the potential exception if you are not 100% certain that the items are `List<Foo>` type.