# Check for subclass in Java

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

I have the following classes:

```
Class Dog extends Animal
Class Cat extends Animal
Class Mouse extends Animal
```

Furthermore, I have a `List` in which I put every `Animal`, regardless of the subclass:

```
List<? extends Animal> list = new ArrayList<? extends Animal>();
```

Populating said list with `Dogs`, `Cats` and `Mice` works perfectly, unless I want to later check what kind of `Animal` there is inside the list.

```
for (Animal animal: list) {
    if (animal instanceof Dog) {
        //do some dog stuff
    }
    if (animal instanceof Cat) {
        // do some cat stuff
    }    
}
```

How can I check for each Animal in the list whether it is a Dog, a Cat or a Mouse?

Comment: You should use polymorphism (i.e. overridden methods) to avoid having to do `instanceof` checks.

Comment: What kind of "check" do you want?  Are you wanting the class or are you comfortable with a String?

Comment: I would like to know which kind of animal I am currently working with, so that I can run a specific code for each animal, i.e. Dog, Cat and Mouse. I think I want to know the class.

Comment: Are you sure it needs to be specific to an individual animal and *not* achievable as Oli Charlesworth suggests?

Comment: Maybe if you shared with us what it is you're doing with in each `instanceof` check, then we could give you a better (read: polymorphic) answer.

Comment: Just as a style thing, I believe this syntax: `List<Animal> list = new ArrayList<Animal>();` is equivalent, and certainly much nicer.

Comment: The list contains all animals which have been parsed from an XML file. All I want to do next is put every animal into the right animal_table. For instance: [pseudocode] if (animal instanceof Dog){ //run isertIntoDogTableMethod}

Comment: @Azar:  If you have intentions on modifying the list, then that form would be acceptable.  If you *don't* want to modify the list, then `? extends Animal` is appropriate.

Comment: @Makoto [I suppose you learn something every day.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575363/generics-list-extends-animal-is-same-as-listanimal)

Comment: If you can change these classes, just go there and implement whatever you want there. Sometimes, you can do that:
https://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/when-polymorphism-fails

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help! I will go the polymorphic way. It seems straightforward enough ;-)

Comment: "Populating said list with Dogs, Cats and Mice works perfectly" No it doesn't. How would you populate it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid multiple `instanceof` checks, you could have `Dog`, `Cat` and `Mouse` derive from the common superclass `Mammal` (which itself would be a subclass of `Animal`). Then you only have to check:

```
if (animal instanceof Mammal) { }
```

A *cleaner* solution would be to move the processing into a method, which you *override* for each type of `Animal`:

```
abstract class Animal
{
    public abstract void feed ();
}

class Dog extends Animal
{
    public void feed()
    {
        // feed the dog
    }
}
```

Comment: wonderful. i would tag that answer as code-trolling if answers could be tagged :)

Comment: whoops... i guess now the answer got a second part that actually deals with the OPs promlem.. . Sorry to have misinterpreted your first attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards such as `<? extends Animal>` are useful when your list contains elements of a *derived type* (i.e. Cat/Dog etc), *but you don't know or care what it is*. They're made so that they match `ArrayList<Dog>` or `ArrayList<Cat>` etc when you work with them in a generic way in methods.

But since you seem to be adding all kinds of elements into your list, you're very well off with `ArrayList <Animal>` in which you could add `Dog`s, `Cat`s or what have you, because they are derived from `Animal` and therefore they *are* `Animal`s.

Instead of the `instanceof` checks, I'd recommend adding a polymorphic method in the superclass and overriding it in all subclasses, so that you could later call it without needing to care what type the actual object is.