# What's the difference between these generic declarations?

Tags: java, generics, nested-generics

How would you describe – in plain english – the difference between the contents of these lists?

I'm looking for a **simple** comparison that can be used as a reference.

```
/* 1 */ List<          List<          Dog>>
/* 2 */ List<          List<? extends Dog>>
/* 3 */ List<? extends List<          Dog>>
/* 4 */ List<? extends List<? extends Dog>>
```

The generic declarations with `super` are similar. So what about these:

```
/* 5 */ List<? super   List<? extends Dog>>
/* 6 */ List<? extends List<? super   Dog>>
```

#### Related questions & resources

- [Explanation of the get-put principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292109/generics-get-and-put-rule)
- [Generics : List<? extends Animal> is same as List<Animal>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575363/generics-list-extends-animal-is-same-as-listanimal)
- http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292109/generics-get-and-put-rule) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575363/generics-list-extends-animal-is-same-as-listanimal)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. A `List` whose elements are lists of dogs
2. A `List` whose elements are lists of a type that `extends Dog`
3. A `List` whose elements are a *single* subtype of a list of dogs
4. A `List` whose elements are a *single* subtype of a (list of a type that `extends Dog`)
5. A `List` whose elements are a *single* supertype of a (list of a type that `extends Dog`)
6. A `List` whose elements are a *single* subtype of a (list of a type that `super Dog`)

Where "subtype", "supertype", "super", and "extends" are the "generic" versions (i.e. also includes the bounding type)

---

Examples with `Number` and subtypes, because why not. Replace `Dog` with `Number`.

1. `List<List<Number>>` might look like a 2D array of `Number` elements. Pretty simple.
2. `List<List<? extends Number>>` might look like a 2D array, where each row is a different subtype of number. For example, the first row might be a `List<Integer>`, the second row might be a `List<Double>`, etc.
3. `List<? extends List<Number>>` might be a `List<ArrayList<Number>>`, `List<List<Number>>`, `List<LinkedList<Number>>`, etc. The `Number` has to stay, because generics are invariant, but you can have `List` or any of its subtypes as the "overall" type of the elements. You can only pick one of `List` or its subtypes though, and the one you pick you have to stay with.
4. `List<? extends List<? extends Number>>` is similar to `List<? extends List<Number>>`, except now you can pick `Number` or any of its subclasses as the elements of the "overall" 2D array. So you can have `List<List<Integer>>`, `List<ArrayList<Integer>>`, `List<LinkedList<Double>>`, etc. As before, you can only pick one of `List`'s subtypes and one of `Number`'s subtypes.
5. (*tricky!*) `List<? super List<? extends Number>>` appears to be equivalent to `List<List<? extends Number>>`, `List<Collection<? extends Number>>`, etc. but *not* `List<List<Number>>` or anything concrete where a subtype of `Number` is used. I think this is because `List<Number>` isn't considered a supertype of `List<? extends Number>`, which I suppose makes sense due to generics being invariant. `List<Object>` as well as raw types (`List<List>`, `List<Collection>`, etc.) also works.
6. Same thing as 4, except you get either `List<Number>` or `List<Object>` (and apparently `List<Serializable>`) as the inner list.

---

As @MadProgrammer said, due to PECS (Producer-Extends-Consumer-Super), any time you have a `? extends` for your generic type you won't be able to update the list, only retrieve items from it. So no `add()`-ing and no `set()`-ing.

Comment: Also consider that the last 2 won't let you update the list and the second one won't let you update the sub list as well

Comment: Superb answer! Please take a look at the follow up question

Comment: @MBlanc Just did. Still figuring out 5, but I *think* I got everything else. Thanks for the brain teaser!

Comment: @MBlanc You know, I'm getting some *really* strange things in Eclipse. When I use `<>` to let Eclipse figure out the bounds for `final List<? super List<? extends Number>> a = new ArrayList<>();`, it says that the type of the `ArrayList` is `ArrayList<List<? extends Number>>`. But actually writing `ArrayList<List<Number>>` is a compiler error. So evidently *I'm* not understanding something either...

Comment: @MBlanc All right, I *think* I got everything figured out. Hope my logic makes sense. Let me know if I got anything wrong or if I need to explain something further.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is concrete: it's a `List` of `List`s of `Dog`, and nothing else.

The second one is abstract on the innermost declaration: it's a `List` of `List`s of some class that inherits from `Dog` -- say `Poodle`. It might be a `List<ArrayList<Poodle>>`.

The third one is abstract on the inner list declaration: its a `List` of some sort of container that inherits from `List` -- maybe `ArrayList` -- of `Dog`. Then you might have `List<ArrayList<Dog>>`.

The fourth one is abstract on both: its a `List` of some kind of container derived from `List`, filled with some animal that inherits from `Dog` -- maybe `List<ArrayList<Poodle>>`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace each "<" by "of".

Whenever there is a "? extends X", insert "or one of its subclasses" after X.