# Using Java Generics Bounded Type Arguments

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism, generic-type-argument

I have a `Box` class as shown below.

```
public class Box <E> {

private List<E> itmes = new ArrayList<>();

public void addItem(E e){
    itmes.add(e);
}

public void addItemList(List<? extends E> itemList){
    itmes.addAll(itemList);
}

public List<E> getItems(){
    return itmes;
}

}
```

The first implementation uses unbounded type arguments, which works fine. As shown below

```
    Box<Apple> appleBox = new Box<>();
    Apple fujiApple = new Apple("fujiApple");
    Apple kashmiriApple = new Apple("kashmiriApple");
    appleBox.addItem(fujiApple);
    appleBox.addItem(kashmiriApple);

    Box<Orange> orangeBox = new Box<>();
    Orange weirdOrange = new Orange("weirdOrange");
    Orange orangeOrange = new Orange("orangeOrange");
    orangeBox.addItem(weirdOrange);
    orangeBox.addItem(orangeOrange);

    Box<Fruit> fruitBoxAll = new Box<>();
    fruitBoxAll.addItemList(appleBox.getItems());
    fruitBoxAll.addItemList(orangeBox.getItems());
```

But now, I want to use bounded type argument as shown below

```
    Box<? extends Fruit> fruitBox = new Box<>();
```

Declaring `? extends Fruit` as type argument means that `List` inside `Box` class will also be of type `? extends Fruit`. And following code will give an error

```
fruitBox.addItem(fujiApple);
```

As at some point later, user may try to add oranges to the same list

```
fruitBox.addItem(orangeOrange);
```

which is not right. So I cannot use this bounded type argument object to create a `Box` of sub-type of `Fruit`. Which is understandable from Java point of view, but then using bounded type arguments seem not useful.

So from the implementation perspective, I have following questions:

1. Is using bounded type arguments a right approach?
2. If Yes, What type of elements can it contain in the scenario explained above.
3. Can you throw in an example, where bounded type arguments are useful or  the right scenario/way to implement them.

Comment: A collection `? extends Fruit` is supposed to be a producer of fruit instances, you can never add anything to it. Look up PECS concept. You can only read from that collection. If you need to add instances use `? super Fruit`

Comment: I found another question, little similar to your question. It might be of some help [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575363/generics-list-extends-animal-is-same-as-listanimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575363/generics-list-extends-animal-is-same-as-listanimal)

Comment: What is the type hierarchy for `Apple` and `Orange`? They should be subclasses of `Fruit`.

Comment: @hotzst - I think they are. The OP seems to have a good idea about basic java :)

Comment: Look up [PECS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

Comment: @hotzst `Apple` & `Orange` are subclasses of `Fruit`

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar But why is it that after changing `<? extends Fruit>` to `<? super Fruit>`, items in the List returned by `getItems()` do not support methods from `super` class? I am getting an error for method in super class as undefined for the type `? super Fruit`. Also, what is the type of items in this list, isn't it `Fruit`?

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out what you're doing is covered by the PECS idea - Produce Extends, Consumer Super. You should really read [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java)

Your problem with List is that the list is declared as some type which is a specific subclass of Fruit but you're trying to treat it as a list of Fruit, which is not typesafe.

Where it's useful to use the `? extends Fruit` bounded type is when you're returning a list to a client who will a) only ever try to read from the list and b) who only cares that objects in the list implement the `Fruit` interface.

e.g.

```
public void myMethod() {
    List<? extends Fruit> myList = theListProducingMethod();
    for (Fruit f: myList) {
        f.fruitMethod();
    }
}

public List<? extends Fruit> theListProducingMethod() {
    final List<Orange> someList = new ArrayList<>();
    someList.add(new Orange());
    return someList;
}
```

The thing to note here is that the returned list is effectively immutable in `myMethod`. Because its generic type is `<? extends Fruit>` there's no way to call `myList.add` in `myMethod` in a type safe fashion.