# Implement generic method with List parameter

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to define and then implement an abstract setter which takes a List of Objects as a parameter.  Here's the gist of this simple idea:

```
public abstract class MyClass {
    public abstract void setThings(List<?> things);
}

public class Bar extends MyClass {
    private List<String> things;

    @Override
    public void setThings(List<String> things) {
        this.things = things;
    }
}
```

That doesn't work.  I get `Method does not override method from its superclass` and `both methods have the same erasure, but neither overrides the other`.  I understand the latter error relating to erasures, but even so I can't figure out the correct way to do this.  I've tried some others like:

```
public abstract <T> void setThings(List<T> things);
```

...as well as a few others. And I've found other questions/answers on SO that come close to addressing this, but none that have provided a solid answer (at least not that was clear to me). I've read through [the tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) as well to no avail.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So Java is quite correctly telling you that you haven't implemented the abstract method `setThings` which takes a `List<?>` not a `List<T>` or `List<String>`. All of these are different things. See [this question for a detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575363/generics-list-extends-animal-is-same-as-listanimal).

The simplest solution is to introduce a generic for your abstract class as well:

```
public abstract class MyClass<T> {
    public abstract void setThings(List<T> things);
}

public class SubClass extends MyClass<String> {
    private List<String> things;

    public void setThings(List<String> things) {
        this.things = things;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I went with your example and it's working nicely. I'll have to spend some more time studying generics, some of the subtleties are still a bit mysterious to me such as the difference between using `?`, `T`, `E', etc.  Nothing a little (more) reading can't remedy!

Answer (score 2):

`List<?> things` is a list of unknown type.

`List<T> things` is a list of type `T`.

These two things aren't the same, which is why you're getting that compilation error.

There are a couple of sensible ways to eradicate the error:

- Generify both classes

  ```
  abstract class MyClass<T> {
      public abstract void setThings(List<T> things);
  }

  class Bar<T> extends MyClass<T> {
      private List<T> things;

      @Override
      public void setThings(List<T> things) {
          this.things = things;
      }
  }
  ```
- Make `Bar` accept a list of unknown type as well

  ```
  abstract class MyClass {
      public abstract void setThings(List<?> things);
  }

  class Bar extends MyClass {
      private List<?> things;

      @Override
      public void setThings(List<?> things) {
          this.things = things;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Oops, I just forgot the `abstract` class modifier in my example but I do have that in my actual code.  I've updated the question to reflect this.  However I need a concrete type in my subclass.