# Incompatible types when using upper bounding wildcard

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, wildcard

I'm really confused of how upper bounded types work in Java generics.

Let's say I have

```
interface IModel<T>
interface I
class A implements I
class B implements I
class C implements I
```

then I have a method with parameter as follows

```
foo(IModel<Map<? extends I, Map<? extends I, List<? extends I>>>> dataModel)
```

calling that method like

```
IModel<Map<A, Map<B, List<C>>>> model = ...
foo(model)
```

ends with compilation error

```
Error:(112, 49) java: incompatible types: IModel<java.util.Map<A,java.util.Map<B,java.util.List<C>>>> cannot be converted to IModel<java.util.Map<? extends I,java.util.Map<? extends I,java.util.List<? extends I>>>>
```

I have read docs about Java generics from the Oracle web, trying to google it, but there must be something I totally misunderstood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question can be shorted as why

`foo(IModel<List<? extends I>> dataModel)`

can not accept argument like

`IModel<List<A>> model`

### Explanation

`List<A>` is a subtype of `List<? extends I>`, so it is ok:

```
public void bar(List<? extends I> list);
List<A> listA;
bar(listA);
```

But, it does not make `IModel<List<A>>` a subtype of `IModel<List<? extends I>>`, just like [`IModel<Dog>` is not a subtype of `IModel<Animal>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575363/generics-list-extends-animal-is-same-as-listanimal/2575427#2575427), so the code you posted can not be compiled.

### Solution

You can change it to:

```
foo(IModel<? extends Map<? extends I, ? extends Map<? extends I, ? extends List<? extends I>>>> dataModel)
```

or

```
<FIRST extends I, SECOND extends I, THIRD extends I> void foo(IModel<Map<FIRST, Map<SECOND, List<THIRD>>>> dataModel)
```

to make it compile.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I wonder how much effort it would have been for you (one person) to sort out the code to be in this form:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

interface IModel<T> {}
interface I {}
class A implements I {}
class B implements I {}
class C implements I {}

public class UpperBounds
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        IModel<Map<A, Map<B, List<C>>>> model = null;
        foo(model);
    }
    
    static void foo(IModel<Map<? extends I, Map<? extends I, List<? extends I>>>> dataModel)
    {
        
    }
}
```

instead of letting hundreds of people (who want to **help** you) do this on their own, in order to have something that they can compile and have a look at in their IDE. I mean, it's not *that* hard.

---

That being said: **Technically**, you're missing a few more `extends` clauses here. This compiles fine:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

interface IModel<T> {}
interface I {}
class A implements I {}
class B implements I {}
class C implements I {}

public class UpperBounds
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        IModel<Map<A, Map<B, List<C>>>> model = null;
        foo(model);
    }
    
    static void foo(IModel<? extends Map<? extends I, ? extends Map<? extends I, ? extends List<? extends I>>>> dataModel)
    {
        
    }
}
```

But you should

## not

implement it like that. That's obscure. Whatever this `dataModel` parameter is, you should consider creating a proper data structure for that, instead of passing along such a mess of deeply nested generic maps.

---

The reason of why the original version did not compile was already mentioned in other answers. And it can be made clearer by showing an example using a **much** simpler method call. Consider this example:

```
interface IModel<T> {}
interface I {}
class A implements I {}
class B implements I {}
class C implements I {}

public class UpperBounds
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<List<A>> lists = null;
        exampleA(lists); // Error
        exampleB(lists); // Works!
    }
    
    static void exampleA(List<List<? extends I>> lists)
    {
        
    }
    static void exampleB(List<? extends List<? extends I>> lists)
    {
        
    }
}
```

The `exampleA` method cannot accept the given list, whereas the `exampleB` method can accept it.

The details are explained nicely in [Which super-subtype relationships exist among instantiations of generic types?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ207) of the generics FAQ by Angelika Langer.

Intuitively, the key point is that the type `List<A>` is a subtype of `List<? extends I>`. But letting the method accept only a `List<List<? extends I>>` does not allow you to pass in a list whose elements are subtypes of `List<? extends I>`. In order to accept subtypes, you have to use `? extends`.

(This could even be simplified further: When a method accepts a `List<Number>`, then you cannot pass in a `List<Integer>`. But this would not make the point of `List<A>` being a subtype of `List<? extends I>` clear here)

Comment: You are right. I was thinking this kind of problem is rather philosophical, so it would be enough to provide just a pseudocode. I'll do it better next time.

Answer (score 0):

Having a method `method1(Map<I> aMap>)` and A being a class implementing I doesn't allow you to call the method with a `Map<A>` and that's for a reason.

Having the method:

```
public static void foo2(IModel<I> dataModel) {
        System.out.println("Fooing 2");
    }
```

Imagine this code:

```
IModel<A> simpleModel = new IModel<A>() {};
foo2(simpleModel);
```

This shouldn't work because you supply a more specific type to a method that requires a generic type. Now imagine foo2 does the following:

```
   public static void foo2(IModel<I> dataModel) {
        dataModel = new IModel<B>() {};
        System.out.println("Fooing 2 after we change the instance");
    }
```

Here you will try to set IModel to IModel which is valid - because B extends I, but if you were able to call that method with IModel it wouldn't work

Create your model like:

```
IModel<Map<I, Map<I, List<I>>>> model = ...
```

and in the corresponding maps and lists add objects of type A, B and C which will be valid and then call the function foo(model)