# Error when custom class extends Number

Tags: java, class, extends

I have a class which objects are constructed with a map of strings and maps of string and a generic type that extends Number, like this:

```
public MyClass(Map<String,HashMap<String,? extends Number>){ ... }
```

I also have another class that extends number:

```
public Class MySecondClass extends Number { ... }
```

In an external method i create a map made of string and maps of strings and MySecondClass objects

```
public void myMethod() {
    ...
    Map<String, HashMap<String, MySecondClass> foo = ...;
    ...
    }
```

And it looks like i could call the constructor of `MyClass` using the foo map without any problem, because `MySecondClass` extends Number, but i get keep getting and error that says:

```
MyClass(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, ? extends java.lang.Number>>) in MyClass cannot be applied
 to (java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, MySecondClass>>)
```

and i can't understand why.. i also have other methods which calls the same constructor using similar maps but instead of using `MySecondClass` they use Long or Integer that obviously extends Number and there should not be difference between those classes because they all extend Number.. what did i do wrong?

**I am using java 10**

Comment: It's a nested wildcard - they don't work like you think they work, you need `Map<String,? extends HashMap<String,? extends Number>`

Comment: But actually i can call the costructor of that class using a `Map<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Long>>` and it works, why ?

Comment: Random question - you have a `Map` as the outer but a specific implementation as the inner - why? Why not program to the interface?

Comment: That's interesting — I can't use a Map<String, HashMap<String, Long>> any more than I can use MySecondClass in place of Long.  Also, are we are the inner maps typed as HashMap or LinkedHashMap?  These details could be important.

Comment: Because i'm sure the inner map will be a HashMap or a LinkedHashMap, so why should i use Map as the inner? 
i use Map as the outer cause i call the constructor using `Map.of()`

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49792654/incompatible-types-when-using-upper-bounding-wildcard . I'd consider this as a duplicate (but am hesitant to use the dupehammer as long as you don't confirm that this answers your question)

Comment: yes, my bad i'm flagging it as a duplicate, thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incompatible types when using upper bounding wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49792654/incompatible-types-when-using-upper-bounding-wildcard)

Comment: Another thought: for times when you want a Map of Maps, Guava's Table classes can come in very handy.